# Using Likelihod Ratio vs Hypothesis Testing to test claims?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood

I don't know if I am missing something obvious but it seems likelihood ratio and hypothesis test serve the same function, to test claims about population parameters using sample data ( correct?). I understand that for likelihood ratio function we need the models to be "nested" i.e., the "outer" claim includes the "inner" (nested) one. The statistic obtained in the likelihood ratio is the ratio of likelihoods.
Is there a reason why one is used over another, given it seems they test the same type of claim, about the value of range of values of population parameters?

Comment: The likelihood ratio test is a particular hypothesis test. What do you mean when you say “hypothesis test”?

Comment: @Dave: We are using, AFAIK, different statistics to test the same types of claims. If I want to test the claim, e.g., the mean from a population $N(\mu, \sigma) =\mu_0$ I may, under a "standard" (non-likelihood) use the sample mean to construct a t- or z- interval at the level $\alpha$ and determine if $\mu_0$ lies in the confidence interval. In a likelihood ratio, I set up likelihood functions for each of  the claims $\mu=\mu_0$ and $\mu \neq \mu_0$ and compute the ratio of them as the test statistic. So we are computing different statistics in order to test the same claim.